# How to determine the child model of a polymodel entity on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

That's how I query for contacts:

```
contacts = Contact.all()
```

Then, how to determine if a Contact is a Person or a Company with the following structure?

```
class Contact(polymodel.PolyModel):
    phone_number = db.PhoneNumberProperty()
    address = db.PostalAddressProperty()

class Person(Contact):
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
    mobile_number = db.PhoneNumberProperty()

class Company(Contact):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    fax_number = db.PhoneNumberProperty()
```

Comment: It looks like the class_name() method is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

you can get the kind and class names in different ways

`instance._class` will return `['Contact', 'Person']`

`instance.class_name()` returns `Person`

`instance.kind()` returns `Contact`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PolyModel` class method `class_name()`. Quoting from the App Engine documentation:

> PolyModel.class_name()
>
> Returns the name of the class. A class can override this method if the name of the Python class changes, but entities should continue using the original class name.

In your code, if you insert two objects like the following:

```
p = Person(first_name='John',
           last_name='Doe',
           mobile_number='1-111-111-1111')
p.put()
        
c = Company(name='My company',
            fax_number='1-222-222-2222')
c.put()
```

Then get all objects and print the class name by executing:

```
for c in Contact.all():
    logging.info('Class Name: ' + c.class_name())
```

**Output:**

Class Name: Person

Class Name: Company

For information about the PolyModel class, take a look at [The PolyModel Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass)